# Is it possible to define a function in a Class

Tags: python, function

I have a problem with my python code specialy when I'm trying to define a function in a Class. Indeed, I want to call this function (which is in a file i called BC.py) in my main program which i called PBC.py

```
Class BC():
    self.nmodes
    self.L_ch
    self.w
    def func1(self,x):
         self.k_ch=self.nmodes*self.L_ch*self.w
         f=x**3+4*x*self.k_ch+15*self.k_ch
          return f
```

In my main programm i did:

```
from BC import *
A=BC()
C=func1(self,x)
```

Then I got this error:

```
The parameters file have been imported succesfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PBC.py", line 35, in <module>
    C =func1(A,eps)
NameError: name 'func1' is not defined
```

Please do you know where i am wrong? 
The thing is, when i don't include the function in my class everything works well,

```
Class BC():
    self.nmodes
    self.L_ch
    self.w
def func1(self,x):
         self.k_ch=self.nmodes*self.L_ch*self.w
         f=x**3+4*x+15
          return f
```

Exept that when i use only the function, all the parameters I defined before are not recognized???
For example:

```
r_0=scipy.optimize.fsolve(func1,0.003,args=(0.032))
```

I got this error:

```
The parameters file have been imported succesfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PBC.py", line 75, in <module>
    R_0=scipy.optimize.fsolve(func1,float(eps_real),args=(eps))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 127, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 183, in _root_hybr
    _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 14, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/home/cfd1/ndiaye/ATACAMAC/BCT_dev.py", line 75, in func1
    self.k_ch=self.nmodes*self.pi/self.L_ch+eps/self.L_ch
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nmodes'
```

Someone can help?
Thank you very much.

Thank you for your answer but it isn't working, i still got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PBC.py", line 36, in <module>
```

### C =A.func1(x)

Now i'm trying with a very simplified script:

```
class real :
  def __init__(self):
    self.nmodes = 4
    self.L_ch = 1
    self.w = 2
    def func1(self,x):
         self.k_ch=self.nmodes*self.L_ch*self.w
         f=x**3+4*x*self.k_ch+15*self.k_ch
         return f
```

And my main program is:

```
from dev import *
A=real()
C=A.func1(x)
```

Unfortunately it seems not working to caus' i have the same traceback error.
Thank you.

Comment: `f=x**3+4*x*self.k_ch+15*self.k_ch` is a damn mouthful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call it this way:

```
from BC import *
A=BC()
C=A.func1(x)
```

Edit for comment:

Please take care of the code **format**:

```
class real :
    def __init__(self):
        self.nmodes = 4
        self.L_ch = 1
        self.w = 2

    def func1(self,x):
        self.k_ch=self.nmodes*self.L_ch*self.w
        f=x**3+4*x*self.k_ch+15*self.k_ch
        return f
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function this way (recommended):

```
A = BC()
C = A.func1(x)
```

or this other (*less used and not recommended, just mentioned as information*):

```
C = BC.func1(A, x)
```

**Note:** I would recommend you to rename your file with a name different than the class `BC`, because it confuses Python. Also, don't forget to declare `x`.

Comment: I would avoid even mentioning the "other" way, since using it will cause experienced python programmers to think "what is this guy thinking?"

Comment: I think it's good to mention some alternatives ways, at least as information. But thanks for pointing it out, edited and added clarification.