# Python class and function

Tags: python

I defined a function in my class, but when i called this function into my main program:

```
class real :
  def __init__(self):
    self.nmodes = 4
    self.L_ch = 1
    self.w = 2
    def func1(self,x):
         self.k_ch=self.nmodes*self.L_ch*self.w
         f=x**3+4*x*self.k_ch+15*self.k_ch
         return f
```

And my main program is:

```
from dev import *
A=real()
C=A.func1(x)
```

Unfortunately i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PBC.py", line 4, in <module>
    C=A.func1(0.2)
AttributeError: real instance has no attribute 'func1'
```

When i don't include the function in my class, my parameters are not recognized and i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PBC.py", line 75, in <module>
    R_0=scipy.optimize.fsolve(func1,float(eps_real),args=(eps))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 127, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 183, in _root_hybr
    _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 14, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/home/cfd1/ndiaye/ATACAMAC/BCT_dev.py", line 75, in func1
    self.k_ch=self.nmodes*self.pi/self.L_ch+eps/self.L_ch
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nmodes'
```

What can i do to avoid all this? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It'd be better if you add whole traceback for first not just 3 lines. It doesn't contain _what_ is the error. It just says where it is.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to define the x before. What i want is then to use scipy.optimize.fsolve in the aim to minimize my function: x_0=scipy.optimize.fsolve(func1,0.003,args=0,0021) for example.

Comment: Absolutely sorry i've just write again the error. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to define a function in a Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515771/is-it-possible-to-define-a-function-in-a-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your above code runs if you just fix the indentation:

```
class real :
    def __init__(self):
        self.nmodes = 4
        self.L_ch = 1
        self.w = 2
    def func1(self,x):
        self.k_ch=self.nmodes*self.L_ch*self.w
        f=x**3+4*x*self.k_ch+15*self.k_ch
        return f

A=real()
C=A.func1(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation error. The lines starting `def func1` should be lined up with `def __init__`.

Comment: Thank you I've one more question. I want to use scipy.optimize.fsolve to solve my function:
Can i do it that way:

R_0=scipy.optimize.fsolve(C,0.004,args=0.003)

Thank you.